# d3js add tag inside another tag

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I would like to create a legend in html like this:

```
<li><span style="background-color:#n;"></span> Label</li>
```

But the output is:

```
<li>Label <span style="background-color:#n;"></span></li>
```

This is my code:

```
d3.select("#myid").selectAll("li")
.data(dataset)
.enter().append("li")
.text(function(d) {return d;})
.insert("span")
.attr('style', function(d, i) {return "background-color:" + color});
```

A few suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply insert the span before the text:

```
d3.select("#myid").selectAll("li")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("li")
.text(function(d) {return d;})
.insert("span", ":first-child")
.attr('style', function(d, i) {return "background-color:" + color});
```

Comment: It should work. More info here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-insert

Comment: @carlo No, not my answer, you should write an answer with the solution that you described, then accept that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in the end I fixed with css float left end the @Asad code.